# Grid inside a StackPanel: why do auto and * behave strangely?

Tags: wpf, grid, width, stackpanel

My google and stackoverflow search-fu have failed me, so I present to the community this question.

(This is all generated using VS2010 and .NET 4.0, in a blank default WPF Solution)

Consider the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Name="aborder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    Background="Red" Width="200"/>
        <Border Name="aborder2" Background="Green"/>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

What would you predict the width of "aborder2" to be?

If you guessed "20 pixels", you would be wrong. The correct answer is 110 pixels.

Consider this XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Name="aborder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                    Background="Red" Width="200"/>
        <Border Name="aborder2" Background="Green"/>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

What would you predict the width of "aborder2" to be?

If you guessed either 20 pixels or 110 pixels, you would be wrong. The correct answer is 200 pixels.

I cannot figure this out and it's driving me insane. It seems like the answer should be obvious; clearly there's some interaction between an auto-filling grid column and the stackpanel that causes the grid to freak out. But it just doesn't seem to make *sense* - whatever rules are governing this behavior seem to be arbitrary. Why 110 pixels? Why not 109 pixels or 100 pixels? I would understand if the auto-sized column failed to expand fully or something, but to have the fixed-width column randomly ignore its width has left me a burnt out shell of a developer.

Any help or guiding lights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why doesn't aborder2 get a Grid.Column?

Comment: I didn't think to put one in since it should default to column 0. I just tested it and explicitly setting the column doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have an answer for you but I have to head home first

Comment: It's worth noting that this only occurs when StackPanel Orientation is Horizontal.  It doesn't occur in a Horizontal WrapPanel, even though that has similar layout measurement rules.  I'm guessing this is a bug.  I would generally recommend avoiding putting things that want to expand (in the stack direction) into a StackPanel, as taking on the minimum size that meets constraints is rarely the desired behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why the first example isn't rendering correctly

The 2nd is because `Auto` means "the same size as the contents", but you have nothing in Column2 so Column2 is getting rendered at 0px. You have something in Column1 which spans 2 cells, but since Column2 is rendered at 0 px it means Column1 is stretched to 200 px. By default, Grid's expand their children to fill all available space in the Cell, so this is making `aborder2` stretch to 200px instead of 20.

I think the first example might be a similar situation, where Column2 is rendering at 0px because it has no content, however I am not sure why it is setting `aborder2` to a width of 110. The 110 seems to come from `(GridWidth / TotalColumns) + (1stColumnWidth / TotalColumns * NumberOfStarColumns)`, so I think it's a bug.

As a side note, you can set a Column1's `MaxWidth="20"` to force Column1 to always render as 20px

Comment: Well, at least you derived the formula to determine 110px so you win an upvote! I couldn't find any relationship myself.

Comment: The second column renders at 90px, not 0, in the first example. The first column renders at 110 (110 + 90 = 200 to accommodate `aborder1`, though I don't know why they're rendered at these sizes), and `aborder2` is stretching to fill it.

Comment: Interesting observation that setting MaxWidth prevents the resizing.

Comment: Figured I'd flag this as the answer since the edit provides a workaround and no more seem forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

No answer for you, but it seems to happen in Silverlight too. I'd assume there's some bug in the arrange and measure passes. If you put a custom control in there instead of a border and override the measure and arrange methods you would probably get a better picture of what's going on.

To try to solve the mystery of where 110 comes from, I'm guessing (200 - 20) / 2 + 20

EDIT: I tried a few other formulas and it didn't hold up, looks more like:

(200 + 20) / 2